# How to create offline installer for postgresql14?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, postgresql

I need to create offline installer for postgresql14 which can run without internet connection at all. As I see we can download `.deb` package via:

```
sudo apt-get install --download-only pkg_name
```

in such case we can get package of the software. But it will be downloaded without dependencies. As you can see I need 14th psql which is not by default in ubuntu20.04. So, I can download it after adding postgresql repository to the apt list. Then after getting it I also will need to download for example `libpq5_14.2-1.pgdg18.04+1_amd64.deb` and so on. I can get dependencies with `apt-rdepends` but I hope that you can suggest another way than getting each package from the list. Maybe I can export installed postgresql from the system with its dependencies and so on?

Answer (score 2):

I generally use the `download` option with `apt-rdepends` to accomplish this:

```
apt download $(apt-rdepends {package}|grep -v "^ ")
```

All of the `.deb` files will be downloaded to the same directory, where they can then be copied to a USB stick or optical disc for use on an air-gapped machine. If you need packages for a specific version of Ubuntu, then one method that I often employ is to fire up a virtual machine that has the very same version of Ubuntu, download the packages, and copy from there.